# Radical of the ideal $I^2$ is a maximal ideal.

Tags: ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R=k[x,y]$, where $k$ is a field. Let us consider the ideal $I$ of the ring $R$ as $I=(x,y)$. Now consider $r(I^2)$, where $r(I^2)=\{x \in R: x^n \in I^2 \>\> for \>\>some\>\>n>0\}$. $\\$ Then show that $r(I^2)$ is a maximal ideal. $\\ \\$ To show that $r(I^2)$ is a maximal ideal, we need to show that $R/r(I^2)$ is a field. Please help me to show that is a Field.

Comment: $r(I^2)=I$, which is a maximal ideal of $R$.

Comment: @Bernard. How can I show that $r(I^2)=I$?

Comment: The generators of $I$  are clearly in the radical, and $I$ is maximal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $$I \subseteq r(I^2)$$

Can you show that $I$ is maximal? What does this say about $r(I^2)$?

Comment: yeah everything is okk. Now $r(I^2)$ must equals $I$ and $I$ is maximal, so we are done. But how can I prove $I$ is a subset of $r(I^2)$? $\\$ If $x \in I$, then $x^2 \in I^2$ and this implies $x \in r(I^2)$. Is it right?

Comment: @abcdmath Exactly.